# Reactive statements triggered too often

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Given the following component:

```html
<script>
    import Nested from './Nested.svelte';
    let value = {'a':43};
    $: console.log('value', value);
</script> 
<Nested bind:answer={value}/>
```

and `Nested.svelte`:

```html
<script>
    export let answer;
    $: console.log('answer', answer);
</script>

<p>The answer is {answer}</p>
```

I'm getting the following console output:

```
value Object { a: 43 }
answer Object { a: 43 }
value Object { a: 43 }
value Object { a: 43 }
answer Object { a: 43 }
```

I would have expected only the first two lines, as the value is never re-assigned. If I set `value` to a string or number (e.g. `let value = 43;`) the behaviour is as expected and I get:

```
value 43
answer 43
```

Why are the reactive satements executed multiple times if the value is an object? Why is it ivoked more often in the outer component?

Comment: I didn't investigate but honestly I think it's a "bug" in Svelte. You're the second person in a row on SO asking about this problem and, as far as I know, reactive statements are not supposed to fire when the value has not changed. I put bug in quotes because I've always been wary of using reactive blocks as events, I always put a check that the value has changed when doing that, and I'm not sure the expected behavior is really specified... But it's worth asking, so I'm gonna raise the question to the Svelte's repo.

Comment: I think it is too. Objects are treated differently from primitives meaning Svelte will assume that they could have been mutated — you can change that by adding `<svelte:options immutable/>` to the main component: https://svelte.dev/repl/379b009922164097bb1418b61b3f5043?version=3.22.2. But in this case there's arguably no reason for the binding to fire on init, and it's possible we could prevent that.

Comment: Thanks @RichHarris, I'm a bit confused by the `immutable` option as I thought assignment and not value change would trigger the reactive statements.

Comment: Bindings are essentially equivalent to assignments — if you have `<Foo bind:bar>` then when the value of `bar` changes in `<Foo>` it's like doing `bar = foobar`. `immutable` just means that objects are treated the same way as primitives when determining whether `bar` has changed as a result of that assignment